# Accumulating values until up to date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on an order system where orders come in. For the analytics department I want to build a view that accumulates all sales for a given day.

That is not an issue, I got the working query for that. More complicated is a second number where I want to show the accumulated sales to that day.

Meaning if I have $100 of sales on Feb 1 the column should show $100. If I have $200 of sales on Feb 2 that column should show $300 and so on.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
select
    date_trunc('day', o.created_at) :: date,
    sum(o.value) sales_for_day,
    count(o.accepted_at) as num_of_orders_for_day,
    -- sales_for_month_to_date
    -- num_of_orders_for_month_to_date
from
    orders o
where
    status = 'accepted'
group by
    date_trunc('day', o.accepted_at);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use window functions:

```
select date_trunc('day', o.created_at) :: date,
       sum(o.value) as sales_for_day,
       count(o.accepted_at) as num_of_orders_for_day,
       sum(sum(o.value)) over (partition by date_trunc('month', o.accepted_at order by min(o.created_at)) as sales_for_month_to_date
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by date_trunc('month', o.accepted_at order by min(o.created_at)) as num_of_orders_for_month_to_date
from orders o
where status = 'accepted'
group by date_trunc('day', o.accepted_at);
```

Based on the comments in your code, I surmise that you want month-to-date numbers, so this also partitions by month.